How to equalise input lengths in a PBIViz "table" dataViewMapping?
I'm creating a custom PowerBI visual using the RHTML PBIViz template. Everything is working fine, but my data inputs all need to send to the same slot ("Values") to make the application general. However, if I try and send 2 fields to the Values input, where the first is e.g. 100 rows long and the second is 200, the "table" dataViewMapping fails. As far as I understand, this is because the two are not equal length, and so a table can't be generated. Is there some way in either capabilities.json or elsewhere in the visual files to append a series of blanks to the tail of any inputs which are shorter than the longest input, thereby making them equally long and "table-able"?
Thanks in advance.
